# Methods from new iOS-version, not giving warning, dispite of older SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, deployment, sdk

I have a basic question about the difference between the "deployment target" and iOS version availability. By example:

---

**In my project I use this line of code:**
[image: method is available in iOS 8.1 and later]

---

**I Xcode i setup the project like this:**
[image: Deployment target = 8.0]
and it matches the deployment info under the specific target as well.

**When I run this code, it works.! But why?**

**How come I don't get any warnings?**

My deployment target is lower than the availability for that specific line. Why dosn't the compiler give me an error here? I'm testing the code on my iPhone with iOS 9.1 installed, is that why? The same thing happends when I run it on the simulator, also with iOS 9.1

---

**EDIT:**

After reading through the [App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html) and [SDK Compatibility Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Configuring/configuring.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000163i-CH1-107837), I still dont get, why I'm allowed to run "MKMapSize"-method, when my base SDK is set to iOS 8.0, whitout getting any warnings? See image from target settings -> build settings:

[image: target settings -> build settings]

**EDIT 2**:

I found an example of a new method that does give med the error I'm asking for:
[image: example of unavailable method]
Why does this method give me an error, when the 8.1 method doesn't give me an error?

**EDIT 3**:

So if I go along and uploads this project to the app store, will the app work for users running iOS 8.0? or will it crash when `MKMapSize` (which is available in iOS 8.1 and later) is executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MKMapSize` was added in iOS 4 according to the documentation:

> **Availability** Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

I too have noticed that the mouseover popup "lies" regarding the availability. It seems to use the version you're targeting and not the actual availability specified in the code, if the actual availability version is lower than your deployment target.

It's either a bug, or it might be because iOS 8.1 is the earliest SDK you have installed on your machine.